# Is there an easier way to check existence of properties?

Tags: javascript

I have a object for example:

```
var extra = {
  field1: {
    foo: {},
    bar: {}
  }
}
```

`field1` is not guaranteed to be set, If I need to check the existence of `extra.field1.foo`, I have to use:

```
if(typeof extra.field1 != 'undefined') {
    if(typeof extra.field1.foo != 'undefined') {
        ....
    }
}
```

Is there any simpler way to do the check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) as well as [in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in). But for simplicity you can check the existence of properties like this:

```
if (extra.field1 && extra.field1.foo ) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: nice!  I used to  believe that it's gonna raise an exception instead.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator.

> The **`in`** operator returns `true` if the specified property is in the specified object.

```
if ('field1' in extra && 'foo' in extra.field1) {
    // true for foo
}
```

Comment: Yes this is simpler than `typeof`. I mean Is there any way to avoid the double `if` check, it's too cumbersome to write

Comment: @rox You could use `&&`

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function that takes an array (or a string) and checks for each element in it, then you can check the existence of every nested property with only one conditional in your code.

```
obj1 = {
    field1: {
    col1: 1,
    col2: 'a'
  }
};
function checkExistence(arr) {
  // if arr is a string convert it into an array before checking it
  if (typeof arr == 'string') {
    arr=arr.split('.');
  }
  checked = arr[0]; i = 1;
  checks = window.hasOwnProperty(checked);
  while (checks && i < arr.length) {
    checked+='.'+arr[i];
    checks = typeof eval(checked) != 'undefined';
    ++i;
  }
  if (!checks) console.log(checked+' is undefined');
  else console.log(checked+' is defined');
  return checks;
}
checkExistence(['obj1','field1','col1']);
// obj1.field1.col1 is defined
checkExistence(['obj1','field1','col3']);
// obj1.field1.col3 is undefined
checkExistence(['obj1','field2','col3']);
// obj1.field2 is undefined
checkExistence(['obj2','field2','col3']);
// obj2 is undefined
checkExistence('obj1.field1.col1');
// obj1.field1.col1 is defined

...

if (checkExistence('obj1.field2.value1')) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You always will have to check both fields, but you can write it in different ways. If you are sure that you are checking objects, then the following code would be safe enough:

```
if (extra.field1) { //if field1 is not null / undefined / zero / empty string / false
  if (extra.field.foo) {...}
  ...
}
```

That won't be safe if field1 can be 0 or an empty string, because both are "falsy" values

Answer (score 0):

Use Object's hasOwnProperty(prop) for this task.

```
if (extra.hasOwnProperty('field1') && extra.field1.hasOwnProperty('foo')) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know if an object has a particular property, no matter where in the prototype chain, you could use the `in` operator:

```
if (myprop in myobj) {
    ...
}
```

Consider that his method will check all the properties and method that your object has and the method it get from the 'language'.
As an example:

```
var o = {
    "myprop": true
};

if ("toString" in o) {
    console.log('toString exists');
}
```

It prints out 'toString exists'.

If you're interested in checking just inside the object, you have to use:

```
if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(myobject, myprop)) {
    ...
}
```

This avoids the inherited method like `toString` and `hasOwnProperty`.

The dirty way is using the `!!` method:

```
if (!!myobject[myprop]) {
    ....
}
```

This way force to convert any `myobject[myprop]` to a boolean value.
The issue with this, is when you could have values that could convert in false, like empty string or null or undefined or, of course, a boolean false!

Answer (score 0):

This method can check any depth with no limit.

```js
function exists(node, chainString) {
  return chainString.split('.')
    .every(prop => node && prop in node ? (node = node[prop]) || true : false);
}

nodes = [
  {x: { y: { z: 43 }}},
  {x: { y: { z: undefined }}},
  {x: { y: null }},
  {x: []},
];

console.log(nodes.map(n => exists(n, "x.y.z")));
```

Comment: I like this dynamic solution. One issue: You mutate `node` and since objects are passed by reference this mutation affects the parent scope. Introduce a local variable and assign the cloned array to it: `let [...o] = node;`. Then you can mutate that local var without any harm.

Comment: Oh no, you don't conduct a mutation, you do a reassignment. Sorry, ignore my previous comment. Great job! If you rename `exists` with `lookup` then I'm totally happy :D

Comment: @LUH3417 Why lookup? `Contains`, `exists`, or `includes` would be better choices.